# React Opentok how to update publisher resolution?

Tags: reactjs, opentok

I have an opentok-react implementation for which I would like to be able to update the publisher resolution. Unfortunately, it seems that OTPublisher will only update when certain values change, and resolution is not one of them. I see in the documentation that getPublisher() should be used to update the publisher after it is initialized, but I am not seeing any examples of how this is done. Here is the component I need to update:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { OTSession, OTPublisher } from 'opentok-react';

const styles = {
  publisherWindow: {
    height: '155px',
    width: '230px',
    style: { buttonDisplayMode: 'off' },
  },
};

type Props = {
  sessionId: string,
  sessionToken: string,
  apiKey: string,
  muted: boolean,
  style?: Object,
  onError: Function,
  eventHandlers: Object,
  lowerResolution: boolean,
};

type State = {
  publish: boolean,
};

class TokboxPublisher extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    publish: true,
  };

  static SURVEYOR_STREAM_NAME = 'Surveyor Stream';

  componentWillMount() {
    this.retryTimeout = setTimeout(this.retry, 6000);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.retryTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.retryTimeout);
    }
  };

  onPublish = () => {
    console.log('Publishing...');
    if (this.retryTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.retryTimeout);
    }
  };

  retry = () => {
    this.retryTimeout = undefined;
    console.log('Retrying publish...');
    this.setState({ publish: false }, () => this.setState({ publish: true }));
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.publish) {
      return null;
    }
    console.log('lowerResolution: ', this.props.lowerResolution);
    return (
      <OTSession
        apiKey={this.props.apiKey}
        sessionId={this.props.sessionId}
        token={this.props.sessionToken}
        eventHandlers={this.props.eventHandlers}
      >
        <OTPublisher
          ref={this.otPublisher}
          properties={{
            publishAudio: !this.props.muted,
            resolution: this.props.lowerResolution ? '320x240' : '640x480',
            frameRate: this.props.lowerResolution ? 1 : 30,
            name: TokboxPublisher.SURVEYOR_STREAM_NAME,
            ...styles.publisherWindow,
            ...this.props.style,
          }}
          onPublish={this.onPublish}
          onError={this.props.onError}
        />
      </OTSession>
    );
  }
}

export default TokboxPublisher;
```

How would I use getPublisher() in this code to get the resolution to update when the lowerResolution prop changes to 'true'?

Comment: The solution I found was as follows: I changed the ref to `ref={ (ref) => this.publisher = ref }` and added the following lifecycle method: `componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.lowerResolution !== prevProps.lowerResolution) {
      if (this.props.lowerResolution) {
        this.publisher.getPublisher().stream.setVideoDimensions(320, 240);
      } else if (!this.props.lowerResolution) {
        this.publisher.getPublisher().stream.setVideoDimensions(640, 480);
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: This won't actually change the dimensions of the video. This is an internal undocumented API to message the other clients when the dimensions have changed. But it will not request access to the camera again with the new resolution.

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

When you call the `getPublisher()` method of the `OTPublisher` component, a  [Publisher](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html) object will be returned. You can then call `videoWidth()` and `videoHeight()` methods on the Publisher object at any given time to know the publisher's resolution. For more information on the Publisher methods, please visit: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#methods

Comment: Thanks Manik, but the issue I am having is with updating the Publisher to change the resolution after it has been initialized, rather than simply knowing the current resolution. Do you have any advice on how to do that?

Comment: @mlaramore Apologies for the delay - there is no way to update the desired resolution after you've created the publisher. This is currently only available for when you initialize a publisher object: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#initPublisher

Answer (score 0):

The underlying opentok.js API does not support changing the resolution or the framerate after you have created the Publisher. You will need to create a new publisher object when the resolution changes with something like:

```
render() {
 if (!this.state.publish) {
  return null;
 }
 console.log('lowerResolution: ', this.props.lowerResolution);
 return (
  <OTSession
    apiKey={this.props.apiKey}
    sessionId={this.props.sessionId}
    token={this.props.sessionToken}
    eventHandlers={this.props.eventHandlers}
  >
    this.props.lowerResolution ? <OTPublisher
      ref={this.otLowResPublisher}
      properties={{
        publishAudio: !this.props.muted,
        resolution: '320x240',
        frameRate: 1,
        name: TokboxPublisher.SURVEYOR_STREAM_NAME,
        ...styles.publisherWindow,
        ...this.props.style,
      }}
      onPublish={this.onPublish}
      onError={this.props.onError}
    /> : <OTPublisher
      ref={this.otHDPublisher}
      properties={{
        publishAudio: !this.props.muted,
        resolution: '640x480',
        frameRate: 30,
        name: TokboxPublisher.SURVEYOR_STREAM_NAME,
        ...styles.publisherWindow,
        ...this.props.style,
      }}
      onPublish={this.onPublish}
      onError={this.props.onError}
    />
  </OTSession>
 );
}
```

This means though that when a new Publisher is created everyone in the room will see the user leave and then return again briefly. It also means that the user may be prompted again to allow access to their camera/microphone depending on whether or not.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that looks like it might have worked, but the Publisher leaving and returning probably would have been a deal killer, since with our application we are only doing one publisher and one subscriber, with the subscriber on a mobile app. I did hit on a solution by using ComponentDidMount to directly update the Publisher stream. I added that solution as a comment to my original question.